# Como executar uma ação automaticamente ao final de um vídeo?

Tags: java, javafx

Segue o código do vídeo

```
package video;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Entrada2_Video extends Application {

    public String VIDEO_URL = getClass().getResource("/conteudos/Video_Final3.mp4").toString();

    public static void rodarVideo() {
        launch();
        Entrada1.texto();
    }

    public void start(Stage palco) throws Exception {

        Media media = new Media(VIDEO_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

        mediaPlayer.play();

        StackPane raiz = new StackPane();
        raiz.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        Scene cena = new Scene(raiz, 854, 480);
        palco.setTitle("Peão Genio Quiz");
        palco.sceneProperty();
        palco.setScene(cena);
        palco.show();
        palco.setResizable(false);


        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

}
```

Aí não tem nada diferente de outros códigos já vistos na internet.
Segue agora a Classe principal, onde serão executados todos os métodos.

```
package video;

public class Principal{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Entrada2_Video.rodarVideo();

    }

}
```

O programa roda de boa, o grande problema é que não sei como fechar o vídeo automaticamente ao final da execução do mesmo! Ou seja, se eu quiser executar o próximo método, é preciso fechar manualmente o vídeo.

Gostaria apenas de saber como fechar o vídeo automaticamente após o fim da execução do mesmo, de forma que o próximo método seja executado após o fechamento do vídeo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se entendi bem ao final da execução de uma media você quer executar uma ação.. para este fim use este método.. coloque sua ação dentro do run()

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Mano, de verdade, sério, muito obrigado.

Só pra aperfeiçoar a resposta, dentro do run eu coloquei o "palco.close();" pra fechar o video e depois me virei como pude, mas me ajudou muito, de verdade